# Preencher todos os campos de um Objeto de maneira iterativa

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, reflexão

Tenho uma Classe

```
public class Objeto {
    public int _numero { get; set; }
    public DateTime _data { get; set; }
    public string _palavra { get; set; }
    public decimal _decimal { get; set; }
}
```

Será que é possível realizar o que estou querendo com o código abaixo?

Ou seja, alimentar todos os campos da classe com os valores de um Array de string fazendo a conversão para o tipo do campo.

```
private void teste() {
    int i = 0;
    Objeto obj = new Objeto();
    string[] array = { "1", "01/01/2015", "abc", "0.123" };
    foreach(PropertyInfo inf in obj.GetType().GetProperties()) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(inf.Name);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(inf.PropertyType);                
        obj_.[inf.Name] = (inf.PropertyType)array[i];
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: O grande problema de usar array é garantir a ordem dos campos. Nada garante que a aplicação tem como saber qual campo vai onde. Para este caso, o ideal seria um dicionário. Pelo menos definido chave e valor ficaria mais simples pra realizar a conversão.

Comment: Se os dados no array vêm da leitura de um arquivo texto delimitado, a aplicação não escapa de ter que conhecer a ordem dos valores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa implementar algo no seu objeto que determine a ordem das propriedades de modo a estabelecer uma convenção para a ordem dos parâmetros no array.

Uma opção é criar um **Attribute** para definir a ordem de cada propriedade.

Existem várias vantagens em usar atributos: você não fica sujeito à fragilidade da ordem dos campos, pode ter mais propriedades na sua classe mesmo que você não queira setar valor para elas a partir do array, etc.

Além das vantagens, usando atributos, você consegue definir mais metadados como por exemplo o formato da data recebida na string, quantidade de casas decimais, propriedades obrigatórias, validações, etc. E também pode criar uma interface gráfica para, a partir destes metadados dos atributos, mostrar uma documentação sempre atualizada de como é o layout esperado (ordem e tipo dos campos, formato de dados, etc.).

Nesta solução, eu me aproveito dos atributos para especializar a conversão da string:

```
public class DadoAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Ordem { get; private set; }
    public DadoAttribute(int ordem)
    {
        this.Ordem = ordem;
    }
    public virtual object ConverteValor(string valor, Type type)
    {
        return  Convert.ChangeType(valor, type);
    }
}
```

Veja que o atributo conhece a lógica de conversão, então eu posso implementar atributos específicos para tipos específicos, como por exemplo a data:

```
public class DadoData : DadoAttribute
{
    private String formatoData;
    public DadoData(int ordem, String formatoData) : base(ordem) 
    {
        this.formatoData = formatoData;
    }
    public override object ConverteValor(string valor, Type type)
    {
        return DateTime.ParseExact(valor, formatoData, null);
    }
}
```

E então você pode decorar cada propriedade informando a sua ordem e eventualmente um atributo com capacidade especial de conversão de dados, assim:

```
public class Objeto
{
    [Dado(0)]
    public int _numero { get; set; }
    [DadoData(1, "dd-MM-yyyy")]
    public DateTime _data { get; set; }
    [Dado(2)]
    public string _palavra { get; set; }
    [Dado(3)]
    public decimal _decimal { get; set; }
}
```

Observe que para a propriedade data eu informei um atributo especializado.

Por fim, você obtém as propriedades do seu objeto ordenando-as pelo atributo que você informou em cada uma, e seta o seu respectivo valor usando o conhecimento de conversão do atributo.

Você pode criar uma classe para representar a propriedade a fim de especializar a sua lógica de setar valor no objeto usando o conhecimento de conversão contido no atributo:

```
public delegate object ConverteValor(string valor, Type type);

public class Propriedade
{
    private ConverteValor conversor;
    private PropertyInfo property;
    public Propriedade(PropertyInfo property, ConverteValor conversor)
    {
        this.conversor = conversor;
        this.property = property;
    }
    public void SetValue(object objeto, string valor)
    {
        property.SetValue(objeto, conversor(valor, property.PropertyType));
    }
}
```

E a lógica para ler obter as propriedades e setar o valor em cada uma fica assim:

```
public static class FabricaObjeto
{
    public static Objeto Constroi(string[] dadosOrdenados)
    {
        var typeAtributoDado = typeof(DadoAttribute);

        var propriedades =
             from propriedade in typeof(Objeto).GetProperties()
             where Attribute.IsDefined(propriedade, typeAtributoDado)
             orderby
               ((DadoAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(propriedade, typeAtributoDado)).Ordem
             select new Propriedade (propriedade,
                ((DadoAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(propriedade, typeAtributoDado))
                  .ConverteValor);

        var objeto = new Objeto();
        var indiceDado = 0;

        foreach (var propriedade in propriedades)
        {
            propriedade.SetValue(objeto, dadosOrdenados[indiceDado]);
            indiceDado++;
        }
        return objeto;
    }
}
```

Um exemplo de código consumidor:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dadosOrdenados = new string[] { "1", "13-01-2015", "abc", "0.123" };
        var objeto = FabricaObjeto.Constroi(dadosOrdenados);

        Console.WriteLine(
            string.Format("{0} - {1} - {2} - {3}"
            , objeto._numero, objeto._data, objeto._palavra, objeto._decimal));
        // saída: 1 - 13/01/2015 00:00:00 - abc - 0.123
    }
}
```

Esta solução é útil, por exemplo, para criar instâncias de objetos a partir da leitura de arquivo texto delimitado (*csv*). Algumas vezes não podemos ditar o formato do arquivo e nosso código nunca vai escapar de precisar conhecer a sequência dos campos.

Veja funcionando no [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gijm77).

Answer (score 4):

Fazer este tipo de operação sempre tem um pouco de risco, se a ordem dos dados ou se os tipos não são os esperado pode dar problema. O ideal é tentar achar outra solução, talvez até mesmo geração de código. Mas se precisa fazer desta forma tem algumas soluções. Vou dar uma que funciona bem se você puder garantir a ordem dos dados no *array* e que os tipos utilizados sejam os que podem ser convertidos com [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_Convert_ChangeType_System_Object_System_Type_System_IFormatProvider_). E é claro que os dados precisam ser válidos para que a conversão seja efetivada.

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Reflection;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        int i = 0;
        Objeto obj = new Objeto();
        string[] array = { "1", "01/01/2015", "abc", "0.123" };
        foreach(PropertyInfo inf in typeof(Objeto).GetProperties()) {
            inf.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(array[i], inf.PropertyType));
            i++;
        }
        WriteLine($"Número: {obj._numero}");
        WriteLine($"Número: {obj._data}");
        WriteLine($"Número: {obj._palavra}");
        WriteLine($"Número: {obj._decimal}");
    }
}

public class Objeto {
    public int _numero { get; set; }
    public DateTime _data { get; set; }
    public string _palavra { get; set; }
    public decimal _decimal { get; set; }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/JsvZx8). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NdfSDH). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Reflection/FillObject.cs).

É possível dar mais garantias mas vai complicando o código. É possível ter conversões para outros tipos mas precisaria montar uma tabela ou `switch` ou uma classe com derivações, ou algum mecanismo que defina todos os tipos possíveis que podem estar nos seus objetos. E obviamente para cada tipo deve contar um algoritmo de conversão. Talvez apenas uma delegação para o que o próprio tipo já faz para converter à partir de *strings*. Seria algo semelhante ao que a função usada já faz (mas poderia ter outras implementações como já disse) conforme pode ser visto no seu [código fonte](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,3bcca7a9bda4114e) ([no .NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Convert.cs,3bcca7a9bda4114e)).